# Shorthand <? issue

Tags: php

I want to use the [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) shorthand `<?` in my project code instead of `<?php`, but my [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server (`v2.1d-x64` on localhost) doesn't recognize it.

How can I activate it?

Comment: There is another location in the php.ini aswell. Looks like this: short_open_tag = Off. Change this to On. Also make sure that you modify the correct php.ini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you php.ini, add the following line:

```
short_open_tag On
```

Note that in your question, that's not what you've done.. There should be no "Default Value: On", just `short_open_tag On` on a line by itself.

Answer (score 7):

In your php.ini, turn `short_open_tag` to on.

This is **not recommended** for portability reasons. My advice is to stick with the longer version.

Answer (score 2):

This is PHP syntax, not part of your CakePHP framework. You need to edit your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`), change `short_open_tag` to 1, and restart Apache.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: i changed it to:

    `short_open_tag
    Default Value: On
    ;Development Value: Off
    ;Production Value: Off`

and tested this code after restarting all services:

    `<? echo "it works"; ?>`

but it don't work!

and this works:

    `<?php echo "it works"; ?>`

Comment: The person that corrected you not following any of the original answers by writing "Default Value: On" as the value is not the person that answered your question. You're not using this site correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can activate it in your `php.ini` file. But good practice is to use the full string (`<?php ... ?>`). Not every PHP configuration allows the shorthand, and you do not have access to every server's `php.ini` (that is, if you host in a shared environment).

Answer (score 1):

Set the configuration parameter `short_open_tag` to `On` in your `php.ini` file and restart your Apache server.

Comment: This answer is now older than half a year and suddenly gets a downvote without explanation. Dear downvoter, do you care to give a reason for your downvote? :) Maybe I can improve my answer after reading your criticism.