# cURL PHP Internal Error, why?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, screen-scraping

I am working on a tool to grab the urls from google searches that contain specific urls. Input is a list of urls and a target url, the desired output is a list of urls for the ads that appear on those searches in the list where the target url is included. Curl is used to grab the source code of those searches.

This is live at http://obsidianpunch.com/Summer however as you can see it returns an Internal Server Error. "Searches" are google search urls, input fields proxies and competition go nowhere.

Unfortunately GoDaddy is not letting me view error logs, although I am hoping to hear back from their customer support about this soon...

I have triple checked the database details, and am looking for errors in the code that would cause this error.

The delimiters for the google ads may be off, but I would not expect that to cause a blank result not an error.

Any suggestions to get around this impasse are appreciated. Thank You.

```
<html>
<body>

<?
set_time_limit (0);

$urls=explode("\n", $_POST['url']);

$target=$_Post['target'];

$allurls=count($urls);

//use the new tool box
require "ToolBoxA4.php";

for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= $allurls; $counter++) {


 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls[$counter]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_exec ($ch); 
 $curl_scraped_page=curl_exec($ch); 



//call the new function parseA1
$arrOut = parseA1 ($curl_scraped_page);

//the output is an array with 3 items:  $arrOut[0] is RHS, $arrOut[1] is TOP, $arrOut[2] is NAT
//to look at the RHS

$curl_scraped_page=strtolower($curl_scraped_page);
$haystack=$curl_scraped_page;
if (strlen(strstr($haystack,$target))>0) {



$FileName = abs(rand(0,1000000000000));
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($FileHandle, $curl_scraped_page);

$hostname="********.hostedresource.com";
$username="*******";
$password="*******";
$dbname="******";
$usertable="*******";

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname ,$con);

$right = explode(",", $arrOut[0]);
$top = explode(",", $arrOut[1]);

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme <= 5; $countforme++) {

$topnow=$top[$countforme];

$query = "INSERT INTO ***** (time, ad1) VALUES ('$FileName','$topnow')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

}

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme <= 15; $countforme++) {

$rightnow = $right[$countforme];


$query = "INSERT INTO ***** (time, ad1) VALUES ('$FileName','$rightnow')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

}

mysql_close($con);

echo 'Done';


fclose($FileHandle);
}
curl_close($ch);

}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is toolboxA4.php, called above.

```
<?php

function strTrim ($strIn, $cutA, $cutB){
    //keeps what is between $cutA and $cutB
    $pieces = explode($cutA, $strIn, 2);
    $str1 = $pieces[1];  //keep everything after cutA 

    $pieces = explode($cutB, $str1, 2);
    $strOut = $pieces[0];  //keep everything before cutB            
    return $strOut;
}

function arrWords ($strIn, $theStart, $theEnd){
    //returns what is between $theStart and $theEnd
    $cutA = $theStart;
    $pieces = explode($cutA, $strIn);
    $pieces[0] = "";  //discard the first piece

    $cutB = $theEnd;
    foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
        $arrB = explode($cutB, $value, 2);
        $arrOut[$key] = $arrB[0];  //keep everything before cutB        
    }

    return $arrOut;
}

function arrElems ($strIn, $tag){
    //returns what is between <$tag> and </$tag>
    $cutA = "<$tag>";
    $pieces = explode($cutA, $strIn);
    $pieces[0] = "";  //discard the first piece
```

Comment: Please reduce your problems code to the *minimum* that is triggering *your* internal server error. Reduce it to the line of code that is causing the 500 error ideally.

Comment: Also, you *can* get the logs through GoDaddy, you just need to create your own local php.ini file and set the path for the error log.  This is usually the first thing I do when I set someone up on GoDaddy.  Not having PHP error logs is a major time waster.

Answer (score 1):

The POST array are case-sensitive, so start by changing

```
$target=$_Post['target'];
```

to

```
$target=$_POST['target'];
```

Are [short-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813718/shorthand-issue/) enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The **superglobal** `$_POST` SHOULD BE ALL CAPS.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php